# Python: class instance created with no argument

Tags: python, methods

When I declare a class, say,

```
class MyClass: 
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value 
    def show(self):
        print self.data`
```

then creating an instance

```
A = MyClass(1)
```

behaves as I would expect (the output of `A.show` is `1`). But when I create an instance without the argument

```
B = MyClass
```

and then set the value manually

```
B.data = 2
```

calling `B.show` returns the `TypeError: unbound method show() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: `B = MyClass` does not create an instance. It assigns the class-object to the identifier `B`. You need `B = MyClass()` (which will throw an error)

Comment: That's not creating an instance.

Comment: The correct way to create without an argument is like this: `B = MyClass()`, but that won't work because the `__init__()` method as written requires you to supply a `value` argument.  If you gave `value` a default `def __init__(self, value=None):` you could do `B = MyClass()` without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B` is another name for the class definition `MyClass`.

```
B.data = 2
```

creates an attribute named `data` on the class definition.

`B.show` is a reference to the function defined on `MyClass`. It is an instance function and expects to be called on an instance of `MyClass` (which is what `A` is, but not what `B` is).

The instance is implicitly passed as the first argument to the function. You can explicitly call the function with an instance:

```
B.show(A)
```